# Why doesn't my terminal show higher than python 3.9.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pretty much as far as i know i can't use or find a higher version of python in my terminal even though I have installed version 3.12.2.

[image: This image shows that only 3.9.6 is appearing]

[![And this image is of applications folder that shows 3.12]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GymaP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GymaP.png)

I have tried uninstalling python completely then installing only 3.12.2 Yet it still only says 3.9.6. I have no idea whats up with it but if anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.

Something I should also mention is that this started a day after I installed brew .

Comment: Did you try to run `python3.12` command?

Comment: You didn't say how you installed Python. Or where you installed it. Or how you are trying to run it. When you type `python` your shell will run the first program called `python` on your `PATH`, so what is your PATH. Use `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Sorry i'm quite new as this is my first time using python thanks for the advice anyway. And happy new year

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain how you installed Python, because without that information, _even if an answer worked for you_, no one can tell if your problem is their problem, making your post [a bad question](/help/how-to-ask) for Stackoverflow (SO is not "for you" but "for everyone", just because you got an answer doesn't mean you shouldn't update your post anymore to make sure future visitors benefit =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because your `PATH` environment has the path of your old python version, you have to manually configure it in `PATH` in macos.

See the old python path and you will figure out how to get new python path and replace the old python path with new one.

Add below code to `~/.bash_profile` and then source it using `source ~/.bash_profile`

Use `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile` in terminal to open an editor
then enter above code which is:

```
PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Python path on macos is like:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3`

Change version of python to the one you have.

Then save it and close any opened terminal. Open terminal again and you should find the newest python version is in use.

Comment: This was the issue thanks a million.

Comment: But not if you installed python with, say, `brew`, in which case brew will literally tell you want to do at the end of the install run, so you _need to explain how you installed 3.12 in your post_. This answer is not useful to people who can't tell whether your question is about the same problem they have.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i see your point and you are correct and i assumed that he is having now two versions on same laptop, but some people may not understand that, thank you for pointing out this

Comment: Why do you assume OP is using `bash`? Current version of macOS uses `zsh`. Why do you assume Python is installed in `/Library/Frameworks/somehwere`? That is not the case if OP installed with **homebrew**.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes i think question should be more clear than that, python installed with zsh will be in .zshrc and path is diffrerent from my answer, it is `/usr/local/bin/version-name`, But if you are using Mac from appsilicon it will be `/opt/homebrew/bin/version-name`